# Laplace transform for distributions

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

The Fourier transform for tempered distributions is well-known. It's defined by $$\langle \mathcal{F}T , \phi\rangle = \langle T,\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle$$For any Schwartz function $\phi$. For ordinary functions, it's defined by $$\mathcal{F}f(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\pi ist}f(t)dt$$On the other hand, the unilateral Laplace transform for the ordinary functions is $$\mathcal{L}f(s) = \int_{0^{-}}^{+\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$Where $s \in \mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to take Laplace transform of distributions? How is it defined, then? It's known that $\mathcal{L}\delta(t) = 1$ but I don't know if it's rigorous since $\delta(t)$ is not an ordinary function.

Comment: @downvoter Why is my question inappropriate?

Comment: Question seems right to me, I don't know why it has downvotes without an comment for the downvote-reason. Uptoving

Comment: My friend, downvoters never waste their time with anything helpfull like leaving a comment, they are selfish and arrogant, they never will leave a comment

Comment: @LuisFelipe Unfortunately they don't leave a comment. I appreciate your support.

Comment: The eight chapter of the book "Théorie des distributions" of Laurent Schwartz is entirely devoted to the Laplace transform. It's in French, though. I don't think it has ever been translated, curiously.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I couldn't find English translation. Do you know any other books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is a distribution with compact support then $\langle T(t), e^{-st} \rangle$ is well-defined. One can take $\rho \in C_c^\infty$ such that $\rho \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of the support of $T$ and define $\langle T(t), e^{-st} \rangle = \langle T(t), \rho(t) e^{-st} \rangle$. The result doesn't depend on the choice of $\rho$.

Comment: Thanks. Would you elaborate more, please? What do you mean by $\langle T(t), e^{-st} \rangle$?

Comment: $\langle T(t), e^{-st} \rangle$ denotes $T$ applied to the function $t \mapsto e^{-st}$. For example, $\langle \delta(t), e^{-st} \rangle = e^{-s\cdot 0} = 1.$

Comment: So you are saying that if $T$ is a distribution with compact support the pairing is well-defined, otherwise we define $\langle T(t), \rho(t) e^{-st} \rangle$, right? Is this the way the Laplace transform is defined in the books? Also how have we taken into account the interval of integration which is from $0$ to $+\infty$ instead of $-\infty$ to $+\infty$?

Comment: Not exactly. An ordinary distribution has a defined action only on compactly supported smooth functions. But if the distribution has compact support, we can extend the action to non-compactly supported smooth function by multiplying the test function with such a $\rho$. Since two such choices of $\rho$ only differ outside of the support of the distribution, this extension is well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

A function $\phi \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Bbb R)$ is Laplace-transformable if its support lies within $[0,+\infty)$ in the sense of $L^p$ functions and there exists $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ such that $t\mapsto e^{-\lambda t}\phi(t) \in L^1(\Bbb R)$. This is a sufficiently general request to ensure the absolute integrability of the Laplace transform:
$$|(\mathfrak L\phi)(s)|\leq \int_0^\infty | e^{-(\operatorname{Re}(s)+i\operatorname{Im}(s))t} \phi(t)| dt \leq \| e_{{-\!}\operatorname{Re}(s)}\phi\|_{L^1(\Bbb R)} < +\infty,$$
for all $s\in\Bbb C$ such that $$\operatorname{Re}(s)>\lambda_*(\phi):=\inf\{\lambda \in \Bbb R\ |\ e_{-\lambda}\phi\in L^1(\Bbb R)\}.$$ (I use the notation $e_z$ to indicate the function $t\mapsto e_{z}(t) := e^{zt}$ for $z\in\Bbb C$.) The above condition identifies a half-plane in $\Bbb C$ where $\mathfrak L\phi$ is guaranteed to be absolutely convergent; there, it defines a holomorphic function that might be analytically extended to a larger domain. This is the case of the Heaviside function $\Theta$, for example, whose transform is $(\mathfrak L\Theta)(s) = 1/s$.

Extending this idea to distributions, it is natural then to say that $u\in \mathcal D'(\Bbb R)$ is Laplace-transformable if it is supported within $[0,+\infty)$ in the sense of distributions and there exists $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ such that $e_{-\lambda}\cdot u$ is tempered. A sensible guess for the definition of $\mathfrak Lu$ is the following:
$$(\mathfrak Lu)(s) = \langle u, e_{-s}\rangle.  $$
Here, angled brackets indicate evaluation of the distribution on the left upon the test function on the right. However, this formula is only sensible for distributions whose support is a *compact* subset of $[0,+\infty)$, like $\delta$ – which is the situation addressed by user @md2perpe in their answer. In this restricted setting (which certainly falls under the purview of our definition of Laplace-transformability), the Laplace transform is even an *entire* (i.e. everywhere holomorphic) function due to the powerful [Paley–Wiener–Schwartz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), whereas we know from applications that in many practical cases the Laplace transform has poles somewhere in the complex plane. But our definition of Laplace-transformability comes to our aid. To see why, observe that *formally speaking*
$$\langle u, e_{-s}\rangle = \langle e_{-\lambda} u, e_{-(s-\lambda)}\rangle. $$
If we fix $s,\lambda$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(s)>\lambda > \lambda(u) := \{\lambda \in \Bbb R\ |\ e_{-\lambda}u\in\mathcal S'(\Bbb R)\}$, then $e_{-\lambda} u$ is tempered and supported in $[0,+\infty)$, and $e_{-(s-\lambda)}$ is rapidly decreasing as its argument goes to $+\infty$. To retrieve a *bona fide* rapidly decreasing function, we can multiply it by a smooth cut-off $\vartheta$ that $\equiv 1$ on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\equiv 0$ on a neighbourhood of $-\infty$, which kills the exponential growth in that region. Then we are allowed to test $e_{-\lambda} u$ on $\vartheta\cdot e_{-(s-\lambda)}$, and we define
$$(\mathfrak L u)(s) := \langle e_{-\lambda} u, \vartheta \cdot e_{-(s-\lambda)}\rangle.$$
One may check that this definition is actually independent of the value $\lambda$ and the cut-off $\vartheta$, so it makes sense for the whole half-plane $\{\operatorname{Re}(s)>\lambda(u)\}$.